# What has happened to my ssh connection?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

This is probably the most stupid question ever but what has happened to my ssh connection?

It is suddenly in color, has that bar across the bottom and looks completely different. Is it caused by a running service that I can stop? (It is a Ubuntu server)

[image: ssh connection]

Apologizes if this is a ridiculous question.

Comment: What happens if you press Ctrl-a, then '?' (literal question mark)?

Comment: @Andrew Having been researching I think I have enabled tmux. Do you know how I remove it? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWheal Press "Ctrl+b x", it will close your tmux panel on `server1.mytechblog.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've run `tmux`, log out if you don't want to remain there. Although it carries a lot of benefits.

#### Edit

If it's already there when you log in, it's either run from your one of your shells start files, e.g. `$HOME/.bashrc` in `bash`, or it is your login shell, check with: `grep "^$USER" /etc/passwd`.

Comment: How do I do that? (and stop it running again automatically)

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have activated one of color schemes, like described there: http://www.igvita.com/2008/04/14/custom-putty-color-themes/ and http://dag.wieers.com/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows#comment-81